# Angular Compilation Error on import but method works

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this external script which is added to the `scripts` sections of `angular-cli.json`

I then import it into my `component` and declare it as a variable.

Here is my component code

```
declare var radarChart: any;

import { Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import '../../../libs/radarChart.js'
import './init-outcome-chart.js'

@Component({
  selector: 'profile-component',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent  {

  constructor() {
    RadarChart('', '', '');
   }


}
```

The method inside the script I want to use is called `RadarChart`, so I call that in my constructor which works, however it gives me a syntax error saying its undefined. Doing `radarChart.RadarChart` get rids of the syntax error but on load of the web page, I get a console error marking `radarChart` (the variable) undefined.

What am I doing wrong

Comment: Since the only thing you declared is radarChart. `radarChart.RadarChart` is the way to go. Now why is this not working on load is another problem, we need to know more about what RadarChart do to help you. Did you try to call `radarChart.RadarChart` in `ngOnInit` instead of the contructor?

Comment: Yes I did try that and gives me the same error.

Comment: Can we have more details on what's not working on load and what is supposed to happen ?

Comment: Edited the OP, But essentially it says radarChart is undefined.

Comment: Can you try to import this way: import * as RadarChart from '../../../libs/radarChart.js'?